# Мультисайт на laravel

Tags: laravel

Нашел вариант хранения всех возможных переводов в бд, но я думаю, что данный подход не подходит.

На сайте есть: категории 100+ шт, товары 100т+ шт, характеристики 1т+ шт, новости 50+ шт, динамические страницы 10+ шт.

Получается, что для хранения всех переводов, нужно делать для каждого языка отдельный столбик(название, краткое, полное описание) в категориях, товарах, характеристиках..., а нужно минимум 5 разных языков, мне кажется база данных с ума сойдет от такого кол-ва информации, не база так я.

По этому хотелось бы в автоматическом режиме переводить страницу полностью, без хранения переводов в бд.

Пробовал использовать [GoogleTranslit](https://habr.com/ru/post/438588/) он все переводит, но главная его проблема в том, что страница с начала подгружается на русском, а за тем через 1-3 секунды переводится на другой язык.

Данный подход мне тоже не подходит, так как в первую очередь перевод страницы нужен для поисковиков, а поисковики будут видеть текст на русском языке.

Еще у google нашел [Translition API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-usage-php).
Но пока не могу сообразить как это внедрить.

Возможно ли автоматический перевести страницу на стороне сервера, если выбран другой язык, а потом отдать ее клиенту?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Получается, что для хранения всех переводов, нужно делать для каждого
>   языка отдельный столбик(название, краткое, полное описание) в
>   категориях, товарах, характеристиках..., а нужно минимум 5 разных
>   языков, мне кажется база данных с ума сойдет от такого кол-ва
>   информации, не база так я.

Не нужно отдельные столбцы. Для переводов достаточно одной таблицы. Связь между таблицами Товары и Переводы, Категории и Переводы [полиморфная](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships).

В таблице Элементы названия элементов для перевода - Title, name, description и т.д.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]